# register protocol for specific httpclient only

Tags: java, resttemplate, apache-commons, apache-commons-httpclient, sslsocketfactory

Good day, I am referring to this website on my code. https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html

And I am using old version of httpClient and apache protol.

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.Protocol;
```

I have register a protocol and the following is part of my code

```
// sf is my socketFactory object
Protocol myhttps = new Protocol("https", sf, 443);
Protocol.registerProtocol("https", myhttps);
CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpclient);
restTemplate = new RestTemplate( requestFactory );
```

This will cause my other httpClient having problem because the protocol already register with this `sf` socket factory.

I plan to do that only register the protocol for this `httpClient` instead of all. But I cant find the way to do it.

Anyone can advise?